# Does Alpakka Kafka Consumer.committablePartitionedSource uses separate kafka consumer per partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, alpakka

I want to understand if Consumer.committablePartitionedSource uses separate kafka consumer per partition(all my partitions say(8) are assigned to single node)

Answer (score 0):

You can run your application and separately use`kafka-consumer-groups --describe` CLI command to inspect which client ids are mapped to which partitions. If they're all the same, then it's a single process / single node

Comment: I have already checked, client id(127.0.1.1-1684083288052) is same for all the partitions in the kafka-consumer-groups command. Does Consumer.committablePartitionedSource internals manages the partitions assignment for each partition and create consumer for each, to make all partition run in isolation and parallel? I want to know how it works internally, and how it is different from Consumer.committableSource.

Comment: I don't use Alpakka. Kafka consumer API itself uses a PartitionAssignor interface. If all clients are the same, then you then need to check if you have 8 active threads in your one instance consuming in parallel (use JMX monitoring tools)